Videofile changes currentTime before keydown-event
I'm trying to build a small video-viewer (mainly just for myself), it's fairly easy to use the video-tag. The problem is when I want to have my own events to control the video. With the keydown-event on ArrowRight and ArrowLeft moves 5 seconds back or forth, but when I press the key, the video skips before the event has triggered.
        <div id="player-section">
            <video width="100%" height="auto" >
                <source src="/video/videofile.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
            <div class="details">
                <!-- Some metadata -->
            </div>
        </div>

    const video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        switch (e.key) {
            case 'ArrowRight':
                video.currentTime += 5;
                break;
            case 'ArrowLeft':
                video.currentTime -= 5;
                break;
        }
    });

I've set a checkpoint on the e.preventDefault(), and when the code pauses at the checkpoint, the video has already moved through the default function of the video-tag, then it steps through my code, and moves it further.
I've tried to see if I can apprehend the move by preventing default in the seeking-event, but the same thing happens there. I tried seeked-event too, but that's not supposed to trigger until after the move anyway.
I've tried it in Thorium, Brave and Chrome, but still the same.
What am I missing?

In this situation, you need to listen for the key presses at Window or Document level.
Try this following setup as a test:
In the HTML <body> part...
<div id="player-section">
    <video id="vid1" width="100%" height="auto" >
        <source src="/video/videofile.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    
    <div class="details">
        <!-- Some metadata -->
    </div>
</div>

Then in the <script> part...
//# If using Window then ID can be auto-detected without "querySelector" or "getElementbyId" etc. Tested in Chrome only) )
//var vid1 = document.getElementById("vid1");
window.addEventListener('keydown', 
e=> {
        vid1.preventDefault();
        switch (e.key) //# e is input listener (ie: the Window object)
        {
            case 'ArrowRight': 
            vid1.currentTime += 7;
            break;
            case 'ArrowLeft': 
            vid1.currentTime -= 3;
            break;
        }
    }
);


Thanks. Didn't think of listening to the window-object, but it makes sense. Unfortunately, it didn't change anything. The video is still moving 1% of the total duration (as far I have been able to calculate it anyway), which is the default behaviour of the video-element. In the end though my work-around was to do currentTime - duration * 0.1 first though, and then currentTime + 5. I know it's hacky, but it works for my purposes at the moment anyway.
Also, I'm not sure if vid1.preventDefault is a typo, as far as I'm aware it is a function of the event, not the element.
